# K-Nearest Neighbours algorithm explanation needed

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In regression model the training process finds parameters for a selected function. But for what we use training process if the algorithm is K-Nearest Neighbours (KNN)?

For example, what is done in the background if I execute the following command?

```
k = 4

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Why is training process needed in KNN after all when there is no constants/parameters calculated (that are needed in predicting process afterwards)?

The steps for KNN are as following...

1. Pick a value for k.
2. Calculate the distance from the new case hold out from each of the cases in the dataset.
3. Search for the k-observations in the training data that are nearest to the measurements of the unknown data point.
4. Predict the response of the unknown data point using the most popular response value from the K-Nearest Neighbors.

...but are they valid only when I execute predicting command?

```
yhat = neigh.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Have a look at a https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/

Answer (score 1):

1) Does training in KNN mean that for each row in a training dataset similarity distance are calculated and neighbours found?

```
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

2) If similarity distance are calculated and neighbours found only for a training dataset then how is class labels found for a test dataset. If we don't know who are the test dataset neighbours then how can we find class labels?

```
yhat = neigh.predict(x_test)
```

3) If we say "unseen instance" or "unknown data point" then does it mean it corresponds to any row in a test dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` has an `algorithm` parameter.

This parameter controls what happens during fitting.

`brute` means what I believe you think KNN does; it stores a copy of the dataset and calculates the nearest points with an exhaustive search.

`ball_tree` and `kd_tree`, on the other hand, use data structures called ball trees and *k*-dimensional trees to represent datasets. Basically, by partitioning the dataset in certain ways, you can determine which points in the dataset are nearest to an arbitrary point *without* doing an exhaustive search.

When you call `fit` in such cases, the appropriate tree will be built.